# document.write style css javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, innerhtml

I'm pulling a bit of html and css from a database, and it happens to contain a bit of css wrapped in a style tag. I then set some innerhtml to the string variable and display it.

The html is rendered properly, but ie will not display the content with the css - of course firefox will. Below is an abbreviated example of the code

```
var outputString = '<style type="text/css">.fontRed{color:red;}</style><span class="fontRed">red</span>'
```

I then set it to the innerHTML

```
document.getElementById('bilbo').innerHTML = outputString;
```

This displays properly (the color red) in FF, however does not in IE.
Is there a character I need to escape for IE? The rest of the html works, and even inline styles work correctly in IE.

Any assistance would be most welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Would help if you described what it *did do* in IE.  BTW, using a style like `.fontRed {color:red;}` completely misses the point of CSS.

Comment: Im giving a brief code snippet. The outputString is set to the CLOB pulled from the db, which in this case is a text filled web page explaining something. I am wanting to display the page as is. It displays properly in FF and not in IE, aka the css part does not render in IE.

Comment: The code pulled is not a web page that I wrote, it is actually nothing but a huge pile of text for a user agreement. So I have to work with what I am given...The code in IE renders without the css, in the example the text would be black, and not red. IE Does NOT recognize anything between the style tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put `<body>` at the start of the output string. i.e.

```
document.getElementById('bilbo').innerHTML = '<body>' + outputString;
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/ScEZ4/1/ for a working demo.

Tested and working IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9, FF16, Chrome22, Opera12

Answer (score 1):

Try this Approach .. Tested in IE7 and above

```
// Create the Style Element
var styleElem = document.createElement('style');
styleElem.type = 'text/css' ;

var css = '.fontRed{color:red;}' ;

if(styleElem.styleSheet){
    styleElem.styleSheet.cssText = css;
}
else{
    styleElem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}

// Append the Style element to the Head
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] ;
head.appendChild(styleElem);

// Append the span to the Div 
var container = document.getElementById('bilbo');
container.innerHTML = '<span class="fontRed">red</span>' ;​
```

**[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/mqaAe/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

Append the `<style type="text/css">.fontRed{color:red;}</style>` to the head tag first.